# Does changing enemy level ruin the 7-3 grind?

Tags: ps-vita, disgaea-3

In Disgaea 3, if you get to stage 7-3 and pass a few 'Stronger Enemy Bills', you can get all the enemies to level 99. Now, apparently there is a bug which will make level 99 enemies give exp as though they were level 320 (I have been grinding 7-3 and gotten one character to 121 - reincarnate, 100 - reincarnate and he is now back up to 100+ and I just made him today!)

I would like to take a break from grinding that stage and go level up some weapons - but now all the enemeies are super powerful (because of the stronger enemy bills). If I pass bills to reduce enemy level, then go level up some weapons, can I pass bills to make those character level 99 again and continue to exploit the level 320 exp trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you re-pass the right number of enemy bills they will be level 99 again. The glitch isn't one-time or anything, it's simply a result of how the XP calculation is handled by the engine. It takes more XP to get to level 100 from 99 than levels 100 through 320, so those enemies give that much more experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - now I have a new one! Can you explain the rationale behind the XP boost?


`"It takes more XP to get to level 100 from 99 than levels 100 through 320, so those enemies give that much more experience."` How is that possible? If I get from level 99 to 100 in one kill, for example, doesn't that mean I should get from level 100 to 320 in the next kill?

Comment: @Laurbert515 no, I mean level-per level, 99 to 100 is a bigger jump than 100 to 101, 319 to 320 or any *single* level jump in between, and XP earned is based on the current level jump XP not the total XP the unit has "earned". It's a quirk in the system that makes level 100 "bigger" than most other single level ups relatively speaking. It might even still be in Disgaea 4 and DD2 but D3 has the most well-known method of exploiting it thanks to 7-3.